# FindOne brings me the value from the cache memory and not the one from the database in Spring Data

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a problem with spring data, when executing FindOne when I am updating a product, to compare the value of an attribute with the same one in the database. The FindOne process brings me the same object that I have in memory and not the one from the database, someone knows how I do to bring the one from the database, I know it's because of the hibernate cache, but I can't make it work in repository

```
@Override
public CuentaDetalle findOne(Long id) {
    return cuentaDetalleRepository.getOne(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. You should `detach` the entity.
If everything is well set in your spring-boot project you can easily autowire EntityManager, and then later in your method, you can use entityManager.detach()

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
...
public someMethod(CuentaDetalle cuentaDetalleToDetach) {
    entityManager.detach(cuentaDetalleToDetach);
```

Then later when using `return cuentaDetalleRepository.getOne(id);` where id is equal to the `cuentaDetalleToDetach.id`, the fresh veriosn from db will be returned.

Although I strongly advise using this approach carefully.
There are some drawbacks to detached objects, for example, you cannot use lazy fetch on collection properties (one-to-many).
Then the detached entity will not be saved at the end of the transaction. To save it you should explicitly use `cuentaDetalleRepository.save(cuentaDetalleToDetach)`.

I will stop here, there is a lot to write on this topic.
But I hope, I did answer your question.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. In my, cases has worked every time. Please keep in mind that every time you fetch a fresh object again (with the same ID), it ends in the first-level cache again and will again prevent fetching fresh copies.

Comment: exactly that is what I want to avoid, I want to get a new object, how can I avoid the cache?